# Record Type in BigQuery Stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, google-analytics, google-bigquery, stored-functions

I am wondering if the RECORD datatype exists in BigQuery ? I am trying to iterate over a number of records present in a table. Idea is to fetch records into RECORD/cursor & then process them one by one.

Here, I have a requirement to delete GDPR records from ga_sessions_* tables. We store users to be deleted in the table gdpr_remove_records

[image]

So I like to call a stored procedure which gets called for each record in this table. Here is my sudo code

```
 DECLARE project_name    STRING  DEFAULT 'my_project';
    DECLARE data_set_name   STRING  DEFAULT 'my_data_set';
    DECLARE table_name      STRING  DEFAULT 'ga_sessions_';
    DECLARE v_sql STRING;
    DECLARE v_error STRING;
    
    DECLARE v_hashedEmail,v_date STRING;
    
    --This one I like to declare as record
    set (v_hashedEmail, v_date) =  ARRAY(select  AS STRUCT hashedEmail,format_date('%Y%m%d',date) from `eurostar-analytics.LOGGING.gdpr_remove_records`));
     
    WHILE RECORD%ROWEXIST DO
    call `my_project.my_data_set.gdpr_delete_user_data_prc`(project_name,data_set_name,table_name,v_date,v_hashedEmail,v_sql,v_error);
 END WHILE
```

Note : Here stored procedure gdpr_delete_user_data_prc deletes given row fo hashedEmail and ga_session_(v_date)

What I am not sure about is how to define RECORD TYPE & store source table output in it & use that RECORD Type in WHILE loop.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery `RECORD` is the same as `STRUCT`

You can use the `DEFAULT` to avoid specifying the whole type like:

```sql
 DECLARE my_var DEFAULT ARRAY(select  AS STRUCT hashedEmail,format_date('%Y%m%d',date) from `eurostar-analytics.LOGGING.gdpr_remove_records`));
DECLARE index DEFAULT 0;
WHILE index < ARRAY_LENGTH(my_var) DO
BEGIN
  DECLARE element DEFAULT my_var[OFFSET(index)];
  SET index = index + 1;
  ...
END;
END WHILE;
```

And from what in the query, the type is probably:

`ARRAY<STRUCT<hashedEmail STRING, date STRING>>`

Comment: Thank you. And how would I use my_var to iterate through ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Thats exactly I was looking.